# Responding to ‘Is the price negotiable?’

Tags: expressions, idiomatic-language, responses

I have been selling some stuff on Gumtree, and nearly every potiential buyer has messaged me asking if my prices are negotiable. What are some common, idomatic responses native speakers use to communicate that they are open to negotiation?

Are the ones below natural?

- What’s your offer?
- How much are you willing to pay?
- How much do you want the item for? (Not too sure about this one)

Thanks in advance

Comment: I was going to offer "no" as a suitable answer, but you actually want to negotiate. 1 and 2 are good 3 is clunky

Comment: The first one should have your, not you. "What's your offer?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a native speaker, I would go with the first and second one, something like

> Yes, how much are you willing to pay?

or

> What would you like to offer?

sounds about right.

The third one, while technically correct, sounds kind of rude.

Answer (score 1):

What's your offer? That's the best question you can ask to start a counter, that way you get a sense of what the buyers budget is.